# Should array variables always be declared as arrays?

Tags: php

When declaring variables at the top of a class, does it matter if I do:

```
private $garbage_values;
```

instead of:

```
private $garbage_values = [];
```

Of course, there will be `foreach` loops within the class that reference the array, and the array may be empty. Does this matter?

Comment: not really as far as I know. PHP is pretty flexible. But you must always check if it's an array before running it through a foreach if you don't declare it initially as an array.

Comment: Ah - that's what I meant. So `private $value` would generate an error if I tried to run a `foreach` on it when empty?

Comment: yes. So either make it an empty array so you don't need to check. Or add a check before doing foreach. Anyway, you could easily test these small things in phpfiddle if you don't want to run a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if you'd want any type of variable to work in a `foreach` like it should, it should fall into the [`iterable`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/iterable) pseudo-type.

So if you use a variable that does not fall into the `iterable` pseudo-type, in a `foreach` an error would spring up.

And in your case, i.e. `private $foo;` if you leave it like that, it basically contains the value `null` which does not fall into `iterable`, so it would fail.

Whereas, if you use `private $foo = [];` it contains an empty array, which indeed does fall into the `iterable` pseudo-type and can be used flawlessly in a `foreach`.